# Spark 2.1 - Support for string parameters in callUDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a UDF that accepts string parameters as well as fields, but it seems that "callUDF" can only accept fields.
I found a workaround using selectExpr(...) or by using spark.sql(...), but I wonder if there is any better way of doing that.

Here is an example:
Schema - id, map[String, String]

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("get_from_map", (map: Map[String, String], att: String) => map.getOrElse(att, ""))

val data = spark.read...
data.selectExpr("id", "get_from_map(map, 'attr')").show(15)
```

This will work, but I was kind of hoping for a better approach like:

```
data.select($"id", callUDF("get_from_map", $"map", "attr"))
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something?
I haven't seen any JIRA ticket open about this, so either I'm missing something or I'm miss-using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `lit` function for that

```
data.select($"id", callUDF("get_from_map", $"map", lit("attr")))
```

Answer (score 1):

essentially using lit() would allow you to pass literals (strings, numbers) where columns are expected.
You might also want to register your function using the udf function - so you'd be able to use it directly rather than call callUDF :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val getFromMap = udf((map:Map[String,String], att : String) => map.getOrElse(att,""))
data.select($"id", getFromMap($"map", lit("attr")))
```